# "Save" and "Undo" Emacs messages with Sublime?

Tags: macos, emacs, sublimetext3

With `emacs`, when one types `ctrl+x+s` (or `Cmnd+s`) but no changes need to be saved one gets the message:

```
(No changes need to be saved)
```

Also, when undoing changes and you get to the 1st change made in that session, one gets the message:

```
No further undo information
```

I was wondering if (and how) is possible to set these messages when using sublime text 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Consult the stack of actions. If it's empty, display messages

Comment: @Thomas: thanks. I know that this is what has to be done, the question was more on the "how". Adapted to your comment: how one consults the stack of actions and forces sublime to display the message if empty.